# Is it discouraged to store oauth2.0 authorization code in a cookie?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Is it discouraged to store oauth2.0 authorization code (not talking about access token) in a cookie?

why? why not?

The reason being the client it is intended for lives behind several proxies and may go through few redirects before it reaches the client. The thought was to put the code in an encrypted cookie for persistence to survive the redirects and not expose it.

Answer (score 2):

The bigger question is what would be the use case for needing to store an OAuth2 authorization code within a cookie; the specification states the following about an authorization code:

> The authorization code generated by the authorization server. The **authorization code MUST expire shortly after it is issued** to mitigate the risk of leaks. A maximum authorization code lifetime of 10 minutes is RECOMMENDED. The **client MUST NOT use the authorization code more than once**. If an authorization code is used more than once, the authorization server MUST deny the request and SHOULD revoke (when possible) all tokens previously issued based on that authorization code.

The authorization code is delivered as a GET query parameter and used in an exchange for tokens; no need for storage. If your scenario seems to require the storage of this code then it most likely needs some rethinking. <sub>If you think otherwise, then include all the details in your original question.</sub>